# AbstractMethodError when execute procedure with mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc

This is my procedure:

```
<select id="searchOrgList" statementType = "CALLABLE" resultType="hashmap" parameterType="hashmap">
    {call SP_GET_SEARCH_USERS_KB
        (
        #{result, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=ResultSet, resultMap=TalkResult},
        #{userIdnfr, mode=IN, jdbcType=NUMERIC, javaType=string}, 'ROOM', '',
        #{IN_DEPT_NAME, mode=IN, jdbcType=NVARCHAR, javaType=string},
        #{keyword, mode=IN, jdbcType=NVARCHAR, javaType=string}, ''
        )
    }
</select>
```

I used jdbc for oracle version ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.

Here is my error message.

```
▶ DEBUG 22:05:34.385 [webtob2-hth0-73 [amap2p_car01_mbl_out-493]] hae.basic.service.dao.OrgMDAO.searchOrgList[debug:145] - ==>  Preparing: {call SP_GET_SEARCH_USERS_KB ( ?, ?, 'ROOM', '', ?, ?, '' ) } 
▶ DEBUG 22:05:34.386 [webtob2-hth0-74 [amap2p_car01_mbl_out-494]] hae.basic.service.dao.OrgMDAO.searchOrgList[debug:145] - ==>  Preparing: {call SP_GET_SEARCH_USERS_KB ( ?, ?, 'ROOM', '', ?, ?, '' ) } 
▶ INFO  22:05:34.386 [webtob2-hth0-76 [amap2p_car01_mbl_out-496]] hae.basic.web.OrgController[searchOrgList:152] - keyword(euc-kr -> urf-8) :����
▶ INFO  22:05:34.386 [webtob2-hth0-75 [amap2p_car01_mbl_out-495]] hae.basic.web.OrgController[searchOrgList:153] - keyword(utf-8) :강설
▶ DEBUG 22:05:34.387 [webtob2-hth0-73 [amap2p_car01_mbl_out-493]] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils[closeSqlSession:193] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@649589cf]
▶ DEBUG 22:05:34.387 [webtob2-hth0-74 [amap2p_car01_mbl_out-494]] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils[closeSqlSession:193] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2a526171]
[2018.06.04 22:05:34][1] [amap2p_car01_mbl_out-493] [WEB-3456] Executing the servlet action failed.
<<__Exception__>>
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.ServletWrapper.executeServlet(ServletWrapper.java:172)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:112)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at hae.basic.util.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:52)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at able.com.web.filter.HTMLTagFilter.doFilter(HTMLTagFilter.java:73)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.ServletWrapper.execute(ServletWrapper.java:147)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.RequestProcessor.run(RequestProcessor.java:211)
    at jeus.util.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1211)
    at jeus.util.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1261)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.WebThreadPoolExecutor$WebRequestWorker.run(WebThreadPoolExecutor.java:340)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.setNString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.NStringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(NStringTypeHandler.java:31)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.NStringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(NStringTypeHandler.java:26)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.CallableStatementHandler.parameterize(CallableStatementHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:61)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:303)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:102)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:120)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor464.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:408)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:206)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:122)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.searchOrgList(Unknown Source)
    at hae.basic.service.impl.OrgServiceImpl.searchOrgList(OrgServiceImpl.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.searchOrgList(Unknown Source)
    at hae.basic.web.OrgController.searchOrgList(OrgController.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    ... 59 more
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.setNString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.NStringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(NStringTypeHandler.java:31)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.NStringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(NStringTypeHandler.java:26)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.CallableStatementHandler.parameterize(CallableStatementHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:61)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:303)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:102)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:120)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor464.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:408)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:206)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:122)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.searchOrgList(Unknown Source)
    at hae.basic.service.impl.OrgServiceImpl.searchOrgList(OrgServiceImpl.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.searchOrgList(Unknown Source)
    at hae.basic.web.OrgController.searchOrgList(OrgController.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.ServletWrapper.executeServlet(ServletWrapper.java:172)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:112)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at hae.basic.util.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:52)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at able.com.web.filter.HTMLTagFilter.doFilter(HTMLTagFilter.java:73)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.internalDoFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
    at jeus.servlet.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.ServletWrapper.execute(ServletWrapper.java:147)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.RequestProcessor.run(RequestProcessor.java:211)
    at jeus.util.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1211)
    at jeus.util.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1261)
    at jeus.servlet.engine.WebThreadPoolExecutor$WebRequestWorker.run(WebThreadPoolExecutor.java:340)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
<<__!Exception__>>
```

I don't know why it happend because just one server(TMAX JEUS7 fix#4) throw it, another server execute procedure nomaly.

Comment: edit you question with proper formatting

Comment: *"just one server ... throw it, another server execute procedure nomaly"* Well that's **a massive clue** which you can use to diagnose your problem (and we can't). A quick Googling suggests this error is often due to driver compatibility. So it seems likely you have a problem with configuration. Fortunately you have one server with a working configuration, so all you need to do is compare it with the server which is failing and figure out what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer for my quest.
This problem caused by low-version ojdbc driver.
 I make my application using jdk1.7.
 Error server use jndi setting, using ojdbc14.
Solve: change your ojdbc driver ojdbc14 → ojdbc6